# JSON и кодировка

Tags: php, sql, json

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая проблема. PHP-скриптом забираю данные с сервера MS SL Server 2008. Код скрипта.

```
$server = "xxx";
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'xxx', 'xxx');
if (!$link) { die('Не могу подключиться к БД');  }
$version = mssql_query('select * from xxx', $link);
$data = array();
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($version))
  { 
  $row['tipv'] = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $row['tipv']);
  $data[] = $row;
  };
$DataResponse = array("data" => $data);
echo json_encode($DataResponse);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что вместо кириллических символов выводятся символы ?. В чем может быть проблема ? Я виноват или настройки сервера ? Спасибо.

Comment: ваша магия без `json_encode` то в `print_r($DataResponse)` что выдает?

Comment: Подставил print_r($DataResponse), эффекта 0, вместо русских символов - знак ?

Comment: что и говорит нам о том, что `JSON` здесь не при делах, и вопрос должен быть _MS SQL и кодировка_. я к этому вопрос задавал. Зачем у вас вообще БД в `1251`?

Comment: БД - не моих рук дело, увы, все данные там в 1251 теперь мне лишняя боль

Comment: у вас по факту если три звена. Кодировка БД, настраивается в БД. Кодировка при подключении mssql в пхп - Настривается в `ini_set('mssql.charset', '....');` Кодировка для вывода в html, указывается в `<meta charset="..."/>`. Вот среди них и копайте. Преобразовывать данные после выборки из БД несколько странновато. Возможно, конечно, но вы их все так переводите что ли?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-set-charset.php это для текущего соединения

Comment: Спасибо всем, выяснилось, что не было ничего выставлено в freetds.conf в плане кодировки, как только выставили нужную client-кодировку, все заработало.